# how to auto restart elasticsearch search once crashed on linux server?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, service, server, centos

Once my elasticsearch crashed on linux server. it gives me following error:

```
Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException:/var/www/laravel/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:51 No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

Too resolve this  i need to reset full server.

I want solution as my elasticsearch service restart automatically in case on crash.

My server configuration :

```
Linux name 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 25 17:04:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can i set something on server which restart my elasticsearch automatically when crashed.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Step to Auto restart elasticsearch services after crash or down:

1) Edit elasticsearch service unit file using the following command

```
sudo systemctl edit elasticsearch.service
```

This command will create a file

```
/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/override.conf
```

2) Now, add the following lines in the unit file.

```
[Service]
Restart=always
```

3) Save the file .

```
ctrl+x  > Y > Enter
```

4) Refresh the unit file using command

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

5) Can check the changes using command

```
sudo systemctl cat elasticsearch.service
```

Answer (score 5):

**Auto restart elasticsearch services in 7.14.1:**

Go to:

```
nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service
```

The location of the service file is changed in 7.14.1.

Then add this line to the service file:

```
[Service]
Restart=always
```

After that save the file and restart the elasticsearch service.

Now you are good to go. (After this there won't be any crash)